# How to suspend an animation in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, suspend

Let's say that there's an animation which would last, for example, 10 seconds, how can I suspend (not totally stop) it when mouse enters the relevant control, and then when mouse leaves, the animation continues to finish the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [PauseStoryboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pausestoryboard.aspx) and [ResumeStoryboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.resumestoryboard.aspx) classes. For example:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="theStoryboard">
                ...
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="theStoryboard"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="theStoryboard"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Control.Triggers>
</Control>
```